# Change UIActivityViewController background color in only the bottom of the airdrop section

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make `UIActivityViewController` as shown in the below image. I have to customize only the bottom part of the `UIActivityViewController` which is below the airdrop section.

[image: Need this type]

Here is a link for the image I'm aiming for https://ibb.co/0sbfQMY

Here is my code but it changes background color completely.

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
```

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556985/6197968

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the view background color before the creation of view. After presenting the controller you have to set the color. Do it like:

```
/*
 * Sharing the app link
 */
private func shareApplication() {

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController.init(activityItems: ["Message"], applicationActivities: [])
    // This lines is for the popover you need to show in iPad
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = (self.view)

    // This line remove the arrow of the popover to show in iPad
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.any
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)


    // Anything you want to exclude
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.print,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList,
        UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
    ]

    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true) {

        //Here you need to set the color
        activityViewController.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

OutPut
[image: Output screen shot]

Comment: It coloring complete view, but I want to color only bottom of the airdrop view like in this image https://ibb.co/0sbfQMY

Comment: @mealagent then you have to customise your UIActivityViewController. Please check it : https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/extending-uiactivityviewcontroller-f24410308699